# Is it possible to have independent multiple axes in WPF graphs?

Tags: wpf, graph, open-source, wpftoolkit, dynamic-data-display

Having **independent multiple** axes for each series in scientific graphs is very common condition.

The requirement is,

The graph can have more than one series. and each series is associated with separate Y axes and one X axis (Time).

E.g. Y1 axis shows temperature and Y2 axis shows pressure against Time on X axis.

Both axes may show different scales (range min - max) like temperature from 0 to 100 Degree kelvin & pressure from 300 to 900 kPa and accordingly the series will be plotted.

I am looking for open source control or freeware which can provide this feature.

I am trying to use WPF for plotting graphs and studying WPF Tookit & [Dynamic Data Display](http://dynamicdatadisplay.codeplex.com/) for that.

Please look at [FLOT example of multiple axes](http://people.iola.dk/olau/flot/examples/interacting-axes.html). I want this feature in WPF.

But I am not able to find feature of **independent** multiple axes in these controls.

Please help otherwise I have to drop the idea of using WPF.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As far as Dynamic Data Display goes, I know that it is very possible to implement what you are looking for. You can always just make a new axis object and add it to the plotter's children. You can then interact and map each axis freely. The key to manipulation in D3 is the mapping, so if you have two different data sources, you can plot them on the same graph dependent on the axis that you map them to, and how you map them. Dynamic Data Display should fit your requirement.